algebraic error occurs in datetime addition
I encounter the following in trying to add 2 datetimes:
    a[9]+(b-a[9])
Out[137]: datetime.datetime(2024, 11, 23, 12, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

a[3]+(b-a[3])
Out[138]: datetime.datetime(2024, 11, 23, 12, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

a[3], a[9]
Out[139]: 
(datetime.datetime(1973, 6, 30, 12, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 datetime.datetime(1973, 7, 6, 12, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))

a[9]+(b-a[9]) == a[3]+(b-a[3])
Out[140]: True

a[9]==a[3]
Out[141]: False

b
Out[142]: datetime.datetime(2024, 11, 23, 12, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

    (b-a[3])==(b-a[9])
Out[143]: False

I do want to explicitly add datetimes, preserving the time part. The out[140] seems to defy all logic. I suspect I have done something really stupid but I cannot find it. a[9]+(b-a[9]) == a[3]+(b-a[3]) is true while both (b-a[3])==(b-a[9]) and a[9]==a[3] are false. I am hoping for an explanation, not an alternative way of adding datetimes.

Sorry, it is python in spyder. Python 3.12.4; * Spyder version: 6.0.2  (conda)

a + (b - a) == a + b - a == b (because a - a == 0). Therefore a[9]+(b-a[9]) == a[3]+(b-a[3]) is b == b which is true.
